# how to get tag values from xml using xslt

Tags: xml, xslt

```
<block3>
    <tag>
        <name>113</name>
        <value>Nfeb</value>
    </tag>
    <tag>
        <name>108</name>
        <value>20234254321</value>
    </tag>
</block3>
```

Here in above xml we have two tags in `block3`.
I don't want 108 tag, so I need to prepare a xslt in that I have to call only 113.
How can i do that? Can anyone please help me!

Comment: consider at least putting some effort in writing somehow readable English phrases. Next time it will be downvoted.

Comment: You're going to find it easier to understand XSLT if you learn the right terminology. The block3 element actually contains 12 tags - 6 start tags and 6 end tags. It has two child elements, whose name, confusingly, is "tag".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="text"/>

    <xsl:template match="/*">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="tag[not(name = '108')]"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="tag">
        <xsl:value-of select="
            concat(name, '+', value)
        "/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Result against your sample will be `113+Nfeb`.

A personally hate `for-each`, but for clarity.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="text"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:for-each select="block3/tag[not(name = '108')]">
            <xsl:value-of select="concat(name, '+', value)"/>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: <xsl:for-each select="block3">
  <xsl:template match="/*">
   <xsl:apply-templates select="tag[not(name = '108')]"/> 
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="tag">
   <xsl:value-of select="
            concat(name, '+', value)
        "/>
  </xsl:template>


 </xsl:for-each>    .................. Error 1 'xsl:template' cannot be a child of the 'xsl:for-each' element.

Comment: bro i hv tried with above for each code but i not gttng 113 tag value  thnx fr helping me bro

Comment: @praveen. Then you are trying against a different XML sample.

Comment: nope bro .. <xsl:for-each select="block3">
       <xsl:for-each select="tag">
            <xsl:for-each select="block3/tag[not(name = '108')]">
            <xsl:value-of select="concat(name, '+', value)"/>
            </xsl:for-each>
       </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:for-each>

Comment: @praveen. That's clearly not the code I've provided. You really need to start learning things.

Comment: yup i was very new this xslt ...basically i m dotnet developer ..i m doing my friends work bro requirement was very urgent so i m doing

Comment: bro got it thank u - <xsl:for-each select="block3">
- <xsl:for-each select="tag[not(name = '108')]">
  <xsl:value-of select="concat(name, '+', value)" /> 
  </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:for-each>

Comment: flack y cant we call particular tag in that block if suppose i need to call only 113 how do we that in xslt plz say

Comment: @praveen. I really don't understand much of what you just said :(

Comment: if suppose xml consists of different tags in one block <block3>
    <tag>
        <name>113</name>
        <value>Nfeb</value>
    </tag>
    <tag>
        <name>108</name>
        <value>20234254321</value>
    </tag><tag>
        <name>103</name>
        <value>Neb</value>
    </tag>
</block3> from that i need to call 103 tag ...how to write that in xslt

Comment: @praveen. You just quoted your XML sample. What's the problem? There can be more than block3 or smth else? Then you need to post another question with a carefully chosen XML sample, from that your problem can be more obvious.

Comment: <block2 type="input">
  <messageType>103</messageType> 
  <receiverAddress>BKTRUS33XBRD</receiverAddress> 
  <messagePriority>N</messagePriority> 
  <deliveryMonitoring>3</deliveryMonitoring> 
  </block2>
i need output as I103N............. input should be as I

Comment: @praveen. This is completely unrelated and should be asked as a separate question.

Comment: okay come there ...bro i will post new Question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5002885/how-to-get-tag-values-from-xml-using-xslt

Comment: @Flack: +1 This is a better answer than the following one. I think that just for basic XSLT it should have also a pure pull style solution.

Answer (score 0):

I would create two templates. One matching all `<tag>` elements which does what you want, this will hit case 113. And then another one overriding it, matching the specific cases which you want to skip.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

  <xsl:template match="tag">.....do stuff....</xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="tag[name = '108']" />

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: hi nick can you xplain me properly because i m very new this xslt help me

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5002885/how-to-get-tag-values-from-xml-using-xslt