# how to get tag values from xml using xslt

Tags: xml, xslt

```
<block2 type="input">
    <messageType>103</messageType>
    <receiverAddress>BKTRUS33XBRD</receiverAddress>
    <messagePriority>N</messagePriority>
    <deliveryMonitoring>3</deliveryMonitoring>
</block2>
```

I need output as if message type is 103. Then we pass a string like CTD.

output: `CTD,I103N`

Comment: Please start formatting you code using `{}` button.

Comment: @Flack: I really don't understand how this is different from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5001480/how-to-get-tag-values-from-xml-using-xslt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="text"/>
    <xsl:variable name="vUpper" select="'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'"/>
    <xsl:variable name="vLower" select="'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:for-each select="block2[messageType = '103']">
            <xsl:value-of select="
                concat(
                    'CTD,',
                    translate(substring(@type, 1, 1), $vLower, $vUpper),
                    messageType,
                    messagePriority
                )"/>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output will be `CTD,I103N`.

In XSLT 2.0 one could use `fn:upper-case` and `fn:lower-case`.

Comment: bro we need to check for input or output if it is input replace I or output means replace O for that we need to check type <block2 type="input">

Comment: flack bro help me out for this problem

Comment: thank u bro ..!! how to check whether block type is input if it is input we need to place I

Comment: No need for the for-each loop

Comment: @fpmurphy. Check OP's previous answer. I personally hate `for-each`, but he had problems with apply-match mechanism.

Answer (score 0):

The for-each loop is not necessary i.e.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:output method="text"/>

    <xsl:variable name="vUpper" select="'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'"/>
    <xsl:variable name="vLower" select="'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'"/>

    <xsl:template match="//block2[messageType = '103']">
        <xsl:value-of select="concat('CTD,',
           translate(substring(@type, 1, 1), $vLower, $vUpper),
           messageType, messagePriority )"/>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```